# Google chart calling PHP script with param from ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I read from `mysql` database via `php` which calls by `ajax with parameters`.
It works just fine, but google chart show an error message `Table has no columns`.

But everything works fine.

see my code below:

## HTML

```
<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: can you share the javascript sample

Comment: It doesn't really seem to be a complete code example. Only a div with id that's presumably used by google chart to load the chart. Add example from mysql response, used JSON, or anything else needed to get to where you are now